# Problem building a matrix with changing variables on each row

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to make a loop for 4 points of a polygon that I'll be defining on my dataset. I'm using lat, lon, dlat and dlon to make these points

```
lat = [35.314166 35.413909 35.533307 35.751982 35.3142 35.1607 35.0475 34.9878 34.9441];
lon = [-119.865953 -119.970299 -120.086757 -120.300046 -119.8659 -119.7068 -119.5583 -119.4711 -119.4029];
```

```
dlat = 0.524893450440127;
dlon = 0.73025079017917;
```

First, I want to make a loop for creating 4 points and save them as the first row of matrix b with the size of (4,4)

Here is the matrix I need

```
b = [p11 p12 p13 p14 ;
     p21 p22 p23 p24 ;
     p31 p32 p33 p34 ;
     p41 p42 p43 p44]
```

here are examples of the first two polygon points I would like to define:

```
 p11 = [lon(9) + dlon, lat(9) + dlat]
 p12 = [lon(8) + dlon, lat(8) + dlat]
 p13 = [lon(8) - dlon, lat(8) - dlat]
 p14 = [lon(9) - dlon, lat(9) - dlat]

 p21 = [lon(8) + dlon, lat(8) + dlat]
 p22 = [lon(7) + dlon, lat(7) + dlat]
 p23 = [lon(7) - dlon, lat(7) - dlat]
 p24 = [lon(8) - dlon, lat(8) - dlat]
```

I got stuck with defining this for loop, I don't even know if the solution is a for loop. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to tag post with language you are trying to use...

Comment: Are you using MATLAB 2016b or later? Your variable `p11` already has two elements, if you put 4x4 of such variables in a matrix, you would end up with something like 8x4 or (what your probably want here) 4x4x2.

Comment: My MATLAB version is 2019b. Yes, in fact it is going to be 4x4x2, as you said. Is that possible to make such a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions. One where I tried to stick as close as possible to the non loop code you showed me:

```
s=numel(lon); % I guess we start at 9 because lon has 9 elements?
b=zeros(4,4,2);
for ix=1:size(b,1)
    %Calculate the indices of lon and lat
    index=s-ix;
    %very similar to the example you showed, insert the data into the
    %matrix
    b(ix,1,:)=[lon(index+1) + dlon, lat(index+1) + dlat];
    b(ix,2,:)=[lon(index)   + dlon, lat(index)   + dlat];
    b(ix,3,:)=[lon(index)   - dlon, lat(index)   - dlat];
    b(ix,4,:)=[lon(index+1) - dlon, lat(index+1) - dlat];
end
```

And here an alternative which reduces the code a little.

```
s=numel(lon); % I guess we start at 9 because lon has 9 elements?
b=zeros(4,4,2);
for ix=1:size(b,1)
    %Calculate the indices of lon and lat
    index=s-ix+[1,0,0,1];
    %Build up one slice
    h=([lon(index);lat(index)]+[dlon;dlat].*[1,1,-1,-1]).';
    %insert h into the matrix. h is wrong way round, so it is transposed.
    b(ix,:,:)=h.';
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked very well.